# Creating an app open to the internet (no login needed)

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to create a simple app on Google appmaker that collects a Yes or No answer from the viewer to a fixed question (ex. "Was this useful? Yes / No").

I would like to make this app available on the internet so I can embed it in open public facing pages.

I have managed to make it embeddable but not accessible without a login.

Is it possible to open access to users who are not logged into a Google account?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible at this time. Only users within your domain can access App Maker applications.