# Publishing a public app

Tags: google-app-maker

Perhaps a very 'beginner' question, but I want to grant access to my app to a number of users outside my organisation. I would assign them a login sent to a registered email adress. Is this possible or is App Maker access limited to the members of my organisation?

Thanks

Comment: limited to the users of your domain only :) cf https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#application_access

Comment: This topic was already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528282/creating-an-app-open-to-the-internet-no-login-needed

Comment: Thanks! Anyone know if this is something Google is intending to open up?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at this time. Only users within your domain can access App Maker applications.